# x11 on ssh -X not showing anything

Tags: ubuntu, x11, azure

I am trying to get a browser running remotely

on an Ubuntu remote host:

I had to run
`export DISPLAY=[remote-host-ip]:0.0`
as it was not set automatically

my /etc/ssh/sshd_config has

```
X11Forwarding yes  
X11UseLocalhost no
```

any idea?

thanks

ps: a Ubuntu 20.04.4 VM on MS Azure